# Javascript Function TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, preload

So, in the function fileLoaded, which is being correctly called upon loading the first file in the fileList array, it attempts to call this.loadAnother() but Firefox insists:

```
TypeError: this.loadAnother is not a function
```

Why does it insist it's not a function? It's being called correctly from loadProjectSource(), but trying to load the next file, it's not a function. Also, debugging "this" has odd results, which leads me to believe this is the culprit. I'm no Javascript expert, but I've never seen this behavior. Does it have to do with the Class creation? If so, why does the first call from loadProjectSource() work?

```
var ScriptLoader = Class.extend({ // Want to add functionality to this to allow PHP or inline loading...perhaps later
    init: function () {
        this.totalEngineToLoad = 0;
        this.totalEntitiesToLoad = 0;
        this.totalScenesToLoad = 0;
        this.totalLoaded = 0;
        this.entitiesToLoad = [0, 0, 0];
        this.fileList = ['./js/engine/Entity.js', './js/engine/Scene.js'];
        this.preload;
    },
    loadProjectSource: function (directory) {
        if(this.preload != null) {
            this.preload.close();
        }
        this.preload = new createjs.LoadQueue();
        this.preload.addEventListener("fileload", this.fileLoaded);
        this.preload.addEventListener("error", this.fileError);
        this.preload.setMaxConnections(5);
        this.loadAnother();
    },
    loadAnother: function () {
        var myItem = this.fileList.shift();
        if(this.fileList.length != 0) {
            this.preload.loadFile(myItem);
        }
    },
    fileLoaded: function (e) {
        debug('Loaded ' + e.item.src);
        debug(this.fileList);
    },
    fileError: function (e) {
        debug('Error ' + e.item.src);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `this` is so weird and causes a lot of problems with scope, one useful practice is to declare a variable `self = this` in your class, and use that for referring to the class within itself.

Comment: What does `this` look like when you call `loadProjectSource`?

Comment: What is `createjs.LoadQueue`?

Comment: Your code seems to be working... http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ET2bB/

Answer (score 0):

It's because of context binding.

In this line:

`this.preload.addEventListener("fileload", this.fileLoaded);`

The context of `this` in the callback function will be the `window` object, not your class instance. In modern browsers, you can fix it this way:

`this.preload.addEventListener("fileload", this.fileLoaded.bind(this));`

In older browsers, you'll need something like this:

```
var self = this;
this.preload.addEventListener("fileload", function(){
    self.fileLoaded();
});
```

Same thing with the next line.

Comment: Although you are right, for this question I don't think either of those have anything to do with calling `this.loadAnother`, though I may be wrong

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `fileLoaded` was intended to call `this.loadAnother`, but the OP pasted in some code with that call replaced by debug statements.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are very weird in JavaScript, at least in my experience, there very troublesome.
In your ScriptLoader class, try doing something like the following (You may have to alter it to suit how your classes work - I don't use them, like that anyway)

```
SL = this;
```

Then in your loadProjectSource function, change

```
this.loadAnother();
```

To

```
SL.loadAnother();
```

Just a thought!

Comment: "Classes are weird" …since there are no classes in JavaScript :-)

Comment: Excatly, that's why i think there so difficult to work with/around JavaScript. I find the working methods around Classes are suitable, for now.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) depends on how the function is called - and the event handler doesn't know you want it to be your ScriptLoader instance.

To get the right context, you either need to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it

```
this.preload.addEventListener("fileload", this.fileLoaded.bind(this));
```

or use an anonymous function as the handler which calls the actual method explicitly on the instance:

```
var that = this;
this.preload.addEventListener("fileload", function(){
    // while "this" points to something indetermined, "that" is the instance
    that.fileLoaded();
});
```

Since the TypeError is "*this.loadAnother is not a function*" and the only place where you try to call that is `loadProjectSource`, you seem to have a similar problem with passing `loadProjectSource` to something that doesn't call it in the right context.